# How to properly run npm install scripts?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I'm trying to execute a Node.js script after my package is installed. But even testing with a simple echo command fails already.
Because I'm testing with local installation first, I've also tried the prepare script instead of install, but get the same results: no execution.

Suppose I have Package A (PA) that I want to install into Package B (PB).

PA's package.json script part looks like the following (tried install and prepare):
`"install": "echo INSTALLED"`

Installing it in PB like so:
`npm install --save-dev ../package-a`

But the echo, that should show something in console, seems to do nothing.

What do I oversee?

**Update 1**

Here's the verbose output of npm-install:

```
$ npm install --save-dev --loglevel verbose ../package-a/
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   '--save-dev',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose',
npm verb cli   '../package-a/'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@8.5.5
npm info using node@v16.14.2
npm timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:defaults Completed in 5ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:F:\public\npm\package-b\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:file:C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
npm timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load Completed in 16ms
npm timing npm:load:configload Completed in 16ms
npm timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
npm timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
npm timing npm:load:display Completed in 7ms
npm verb logfile C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-02T13_10_48_164Z-debug-0.log
npm timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 17ms
npm timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
npm timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
npm timing npm:load Completed in 42ms
npm timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
npm timing idealTree:init Completed in 237ms
npm timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 26ms
npm verb shrinkwrap failed to load node_modules/.package-lock.json missing from node_modules: ../package-c
npm timing idealTree:#root Completed in 16ms
npm timing idealTree:node_modules/package-a Completed in 0ms
npm timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 18ms
npm timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 3ms
npm timing idealTree Completed in 292ms
npm timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 560ms
npm timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 13ms
npm timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:createSparse Completed in 3ms
npm timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
npm verb reify failed optional dependency F:\public\npm\package-b\node_modules\fsevents
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/fsevents Completed in 21ms
npm timing reifyNode:node_modules/package-a Completed in 24ms
npm timing reify:unpack Completed in 24ms
npm timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
npm timing build:queue Completed in 0ms
npm timing build:deps Completed in 2ms
npm timing build:queue Completed in 1ms
npm timing build:links Completed in 1ms
npm timing build Completed in 4ms
npm timing reify:build Completed in 5ms
npm timing reify:trash Completed in 1ms
npm timing reify:save Completed in 64ms
npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 422ms
npm timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 429ms
npm timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
npm timing reify:audit Completed in 430ms
npm timing reify Completed in 1015ms

added 1 package, and audited 480 packages in 1s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm timing command:install Completed in 1022ms
npm verb exit 0
npm timing npm Completed in 1383ms
npm info ok
```

**Update 2**

I've noticed I can run `npm install .` inside PA and my NPM script is executed. So the question here is: How do I get scripts executed if package is installed by another one?

Answer (score 1):

Try naming your script `postinstall`, so the script runs automatically after issuing `npm install`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "echo INSTALLED"
}
```

Comment: Same result - no output.

Comment: As updated in my post: I've noticed it's not an issue with the script itself, but with getting it to run during installation by a third party package (PB in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still don't understand why, but my solution to get it up and running is:

- If using a local path:

  1. Use `prepare` instead of `install` or `postinstall`
  2. `prepare` seems to only execute if there is also an `install` script available in `package.json`.
  3. `install` may not be empty. So an echo or such is at least required.
- If using local *.tgz package use `install` instead (maybe just run prepare)

As said, I still don't know why it is working like that, because I always understood that behaviour a bit more different than it seems to be.

So further explanation of someone who knows why it only works like that is highly appreciated.